# Azure Web Site publish profile using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web site built using ASP.NET MVC4 that I can publish fine to both Azure Websites and a W2K8 R2 server using Visual Studio **2012's** `Publish web application` wizard.

I also have successfully configured VS **2010** to publish to my W2K8 R2 server using the old VS 2010 `Publish Web` wizard.

However, this old VS 2010 wizard does not work with the "publish profiles" from **Windows Azure Web Sites**. I assume there is a version of the **new** wizard that works with VS 2010, but I cannot figure out how to install it, or if I already have it installed, access it.

I thought there was a command line tool that did this, but digging into `msbuild` and `web deploy` provided with no love.

**How does one publish an ASP.NET MVC4 app to Azure Web Sites using VS 2010?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the tools for Visual Studio 2010 on the [Microsoft Windows Azure .NET developer center downloads page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/downloads/). Hope that helps!

Comment: Turns out I only THOUGHT I had installed those tools. The installer was sitting behind another window on my 2nd monitor and hadn't actually run. Now that I let it run, I see that this installer replaces the old VS 2010 tool with the new one. Thanks.

Comment: There a better URL at this time for using Web Employ with VS 2010:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/

And this next reference seems to show how to Web Deploy to Azure, from VS 2010:
"Windows Azure Web Sites – Using WebDeploy without the New Tools"
https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/windows-azure-web-sites-using-webdeploy-without-the-new-tools/